# Jasmine test fails in AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have create in AngularJS the following basic factory that retrieves an array of objects:

```
angular.
module('core.beer-retriever').
factory('Beer', ['$resource',
  ($resource) => {
    return $resource('https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/v2/beers', {}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true
      },
    });
  },
]);
```

I have created the following test with Jasmine:

```
  describe('Beer Service', function() {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('core.beer-retriever'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {
      let beersRetrieved = {
        results: [{
          "id": 192,
          "name": "Punk IPA 2007 - 2010",
        }]
      };
      $httpBackend.whenGET('https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/v2/beers')
        .respond(beersRetrieved);
    }));

    it('is defined', inject(function(Beer) {
      expect(Beer).toBeDefined();
    }));

    it('returns a resource function', inject(function(Beer) {
      const output = Beer;
      expect(output).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
      expect(output.query({}.$promise)).toBeDefined();
    }));

    it('returns beers',
      inject(function(Beer) {
        const output = Beer.query();
        expect(output.length).toEqual(1);
        expect(output[0].id).toEqual(192);
        httpBackend.flush();
      }));
  });
```

The first two tests are successful, but the third fails:

```
Expected 0 to equal 1.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
            at Object.<anonymous> (app/core/beer-retriever/beer-retriever.spec.js:29:25)
            at Object.invoke (app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4862:19)
            at Object.WorkFn (app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3170:20)
```

How can I figure out where the problem is?

Comment: You haven't flushed $httpBackend.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You need $httpBackend.flush()  for the mocked response to take effect.

Comment: I have added: $httpBackend.flush(); after $httpBackend.whenGET('https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/v2/beers')
        .respond(beersRetrieved); but now all 3 tests fail

Comment: There's no point do to it there (I'm quite sure it says in the error why exactly you shouldn't do that). You should add it after doing a request, ie. Beer.query().

Comment: thanks for the help. I have added there but it still fails

Comment: 'fails' doesn't explain anything. The reason should be explained in the errors you get in test report.

Comment: I have added the error above in the description

Comment: the flush() may not be in the right place. I have tried however to add it in the beforeEach() function but the problem persists

Comment: You don't have to put it everywhere blindly, it should be placed right after Beer.query() . You have problems with error reporting. There should be error messages, but they are not there (expectation fails are just the results of these errors). It's not possible to help you if you don't have the information on what exactly is wrong. If you're using Phantomjs, try to switch to Chrome and see if this will help with error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add a resolve function to your resource promise object.
checkout this working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jpiyLuA76BwtrQaSulCL?p=preview)

```
output.$promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        output = data[0].results;
      });
```

And full spec looks as shown below:

```
  it('returns beers',
    inject(function(Beer, $httpBackend) {
      var output = Beer.query();
      output.$promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        output = data[0].results;
      });
      $httpBackend.flush();
      console.log('a11: ' + JSON.stringify(output));
      expect(output.length).toEqual(1);
      console.log(output[0].id);
      expect(output[0].id).toEqual(192);
    }));
```